# Format-specifier following a percent sign in R

Tags: r, printf

I'm having trouble understanding **why** the following two lead to errors

```
> sprintf("\"% %s%\"", "fdsf")
Error in sprintf("\"% %s%\"", "fdsf") : 
  invalid format '% %s'; use format %s for character objects
> sprintf("\"%%d%\"", 2)
Error in sprintf("\"%%d%\"", 2) : unrecognised format specification '%"'
```

R version 3.6.2

And so how would one use a specifier immediately following a percent sign?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output. Do you need `sprintf("%%%s", "fdsf")#
[1] "%fdsf"`

Comment: @akrun, I'm expecting something like "% fdsf%" in the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can evaluate the `%` literally with `%%`

```
sprintf("%%%s%%", "fdsf")
#[1] "%fdsf%"
```

Or just use `paste`

```
paste0("%", "fdsf", "%")
```